# VBA Workbook_Open for Specific Date (Current Date)

Tags: excel, vba

I had created a workbook with sheet1 named as 1 and sheet2 as 2 and continue until 3 (as Month). I had a Date on each sheet on B2 Cell and my date format is 01-Jan-2019 but other sheets i use `='1'!+1` formula for continues of Date.
I use this VBA code in "ThisWorkbook":

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("26").Activate
    Range("B1:B3").Find(Date).Select
End Sub
```

All I want is Open the specific Sheet depending on current Date.

Thank You Guys!! Appreciate.......

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "continue until 3 (as Month)"?

Comment: Sorry for the typo error. Thats "continue until 31 (end of month). Sorry again for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374272/vba-workbook-open-for-specific-date-current-date
'VBA Workbook_Open for Specific Date (Current Date)

Sub CreateWorkbookWith31Sheets()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim iCt As Integer
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
With wb.Worksheets
For iCt = 1 To .Count
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Name = iCt
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Range("B2").Value = DateSerial(2019, 1, iCt)
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Range("B2").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Next iCt
For iCt = iCt To 31
    .Add After:=wb.Worksheets(.Count)
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Name = iCt
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Range("B2").Value = DateSerial(2019, 1, iCt)
    wb.Worksheets(iCt).Range("B2").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Next iCt
End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\mySpecialFolder\my31days.xlsb", _  
    FileFormat:=xlExcel12
End Sub

'Copy this Subroutine to "ThisWorkbook" of the newly created workbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim actDay As Integer
    actDay = Format(Date, "d")
    Worksheets(actDay).Activate
End Sub
```

**=> This workbook will open and activate the

.   sheet "26" if today is the 26th of the month!**

Comment: Thank You So Much @simple-solution. IT's WORKING. You are AMAZING